# Model looks odd in ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

I've created simple model. It worked fine, but next time after opening ArcGIS I saw model in that way:

[image]

Used tools are not orange but white and I can't click on them (to edit something).

When I run my model it still works properly, but I'd like to change something which is impossible.

Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: Have you tried successively restarting ArcMap, rebooting and deleting/renaming your Normal.mxt?

Comment: I've seen a few postings on forums where model builder looks like this. What OS, screen resolution,graphics card are you using, best update your question with those specs?

Comment: Using Windows Explorer, copy the toolbox to your desktop.  Then open the copy in ArcGIS.  Does the copy work OK?